# Error using unity in mapping objects in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, unity-container

I am seeing an issue in using of unity in controller constructor. Here are the details -

In unit configuration (unity.config)– here is what I am doing –

```
container.RegisterType<ISessionWrapper, SessionWrapper>()
```

**In the Controller constructor**

```
    public OnboardingController( ISessionWrapper sessionwrapper )
    {
        SessionWrapper = sessionwrapper;
    }
```

**SessionWrapper**

public interface ISessionWrapper
    {
        string Brand { get; set; }
        //string CurrenSessionCulture { get; set; }
    }

```
public class SessionWrapper : ISessionWrapper
{
    public string Brand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Error occuring in doing this

**No parameterless constructor defined for this object.** 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Source Error:** 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.****

When I change the Controller Constructor definition like this it is all working fine.

```
    public OnboardingController()
        : this(new SessionWrapper())
    {
        //
    }
```

Comment: Do you call DependencyResolver.SetResolver() in your config code?

Comment: How are you constructing (creating) your OnboardingController ?

Comment: are you using the PerRequestLifetimeManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a custom [ControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory(v=vs.118).aspx) using Unity to resolve instances of your controller classes. The default ControllerFactory used by MVC requires that the controller classes have a parameterless constructor.

A custom ControllerFactory using Unity looks like

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
  private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

  public UnityControllerFactory (IUnityContainer container) {
    _container = container;
  }

  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
    if (controllerType != null) {
        return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
    }
    else {
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
  }
}
```

On application start (normally in the global.asax) you register your ControllerFactory in the MVC Runtime using the following code

```
var container = // initialize your unity container
var factory = new UnityControllerFactory(container);
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
```